# How can I target an X window to a secondary monitor? (and know what it is called in order to do that)

Tags: x11, xorg, display, multi-monitor, unix-sockets

- I have two monitors connected (one HDMI, one DVI) connected to an Nvidia GT710 GPU on my linux box.
- When I am logged in to my box over ssh, if I run `xeyes` it will always run on the same screen.
- I know the name of this screen because `echo $DISPLAY` returns `:0`

Based on some what I have read, I expected to be able to target X windows to my left and right monitor using `:0.0` and `:0.1` respectively. Same for `:1`.
`DISPLAY=:0.0 xeyes` indeed does bring up xeyes on the left screen, but:

```
~$ DISPLAY=:0.1 xeyes
Error: Can't open display: :0.1
```

I thought that maybe I could see what the name of my right display is by listing `/tmp/.X11-unix/` but:

```
~$ ls /tmp/.X11-unix/
X0
```

So how do I address this secondary display and know what to address it as?

PS. I don't care if I can't move windows between screens, as described here in the ArchWiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Multihead#Separate_screens. This would be fine for me, but it is not clear from me how to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expected to be able to target X windows to my left and right monitor using :0.0 and :0.1

This is only true of your left and right monitor would actually use two **X screens**, which isn't something you'd normally see unless you've configured it yourself.

Out of the box, most of today's system use **Xinerama**, which means you get a single **X screen** with two `xrandr` outputs reading from the same framebuffer in different locations.

But only you can tell us how your system is configured (read `/var/log/Xorg.log` to find out).

> Error: Can't open display: :0.1

That confirms the assumption made above: You don't have two X screens.

> So how do I address this secondary display and know what to address it as?

Look at the output of `xrandr`, see if you have two **outputs** attached to the same framebuffer (i.e., all are listed under `Screen 0`).

If yes, this means you need to place a window on a certain position to have it appear on the left or on the right monitor (or on both, one half on the left, the other half on the right).

Your **Window Manager** (WM), which on most modern distributions is integrated in your desktop environment, can influence the placement of windows, and by configuring it correctly, it can help placing it on the position (and therefore monitor) you want.

Many (but not all) X applications also support the `-geometry` option (read the man page), which again would place the window at a certain position, but the WM is free to override that, so if it doesn't work, that's why.

---

If you are not running a modern desktop system, and if you don't even plan to use a window manager (which even decades ago everyone did; X is **meant** to have a window manager), then you need to position and size each window individually via the commandline (and that will also determine on which screen they appear in your current setip); you won't be able to resize or move windows, etc. (And if you **can** do this, then you have some WM somewhere, even if you don't realize this).

You also **can** set up X so it uses two screens, one for each output. You need a custom `xorg.conf` file. Here's the file I used for Intel hardware with one screen for HDMI3 (when I attached my TV a while back, that's why having two screens made sense):

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier "intel0"
        Driver "intel"
        Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
        Option "ZaphodHeads" "VGA1,HDMI1,DP1"
        Screen 0
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier "intel1"
        Driver "intel"
        Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
        Option "ZaphodHeads" "HDMI3"
        Screen 1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "screen0"
        Device "intel0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "screen1"
        Device "intel1"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier "default"
        Screen "screen0" 0 0
        Screen "screen1" Below "screen0"
EndSection
```

You'll need to adapt this to your hardware and requirements; different hardware might need different options (for example, back then when I did this, Intel hardware needed the AccelMethod and ZaphodHeads). Expect to spend quite a bit of time to make this work right.

Comment: Thanks. You are correct about the output of `xrandr`, both outputs are listed under `0`. I am not using a window manager, which is why I am trying to do all this stuff manually. I guess there is no way to force each physical output to have its own X screen, is there?

Comment: Thanks for the update! In case you are wondering why I decided not to use a desktop is because this is computer is acting as a host for containers and VMs. The only reason I even need X is so that LXC can create GUI windows.

Comment: Not sure what "GUI windows" you are talking about - LXC should work purely from the commandline, and if you are talking about windows created by apps inside the containers, you can use `Xdummy` or `Xvfb`; you don't need real hardware.

Comment: Yes, windows created by apps inside the containers is what I meant. I thought `xdummy` was for when no physical monitors are attached, I will have to look into that and `Xvfb`. I'm not clear on how they would help my use case.

Comment: From your description I thought your use case was "let the apps create those windows, but I don't care for them, because I don't use them". Which means then you have an X server where you don't see them. If you actually want to use the windows, at least I would like to have a WM, so I can move windows around, resize then, maximize/minimize them, etc. But YMMV, of course.

Comment: Also, the typical container use case is that you want to keep everything in a container in isolation from other containers. You don't use shared resources. So in that case, if something in the container produces windows and you occasionally want to interact with those windows, you again run some sort of "virtual" X server inside the container, and connect to it from the outside (e.g. with VNC).

Comment: I won't need to move windows around. My intention is for each containerized desktop to appear on a different monitor. But for starters I am just trying to target `xeyes` to one screen/physical monitor or the other.